# SSIS Flat File Wildcard Filename

Tags: ssis

I want to load a .csv file that is dropped in a specific directory but the filename is suffixed with YYYYMMDD, eg. MyFile_YYYYMMDD.csv.

The directory is cleared out everyday and a new file is dropped, ie. there is only ever 1 file in the directory.

Is there a (simple?) way to code a wildcard filename, eg. MyFile_*.csv, that can be used by the Connection Manager without having to use a Foreach Loop Container or a Script?

Comment: You've already mentioned the two standard solutions for this situations: a Foreach container and a Script Task. Why are they not suitable for your needs? What is not "simple" about them?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with the `Foreach Loop Container` you can use the `Foreach File Enumerator` to loop through a certain directory. In the `Files` property of that enumerator you can use wildcards, e.g., MyFile_*.csv.

Map a variable to the fully qualified file name and push that variable to your connection manager with an expression.

Comment: what other wildcard are available?