# File identification using part of a filename in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I hoping someone can help me or can point in the direction as a search didn't return something that was what I was looking for.

I'm still fairly new to SSIS and I've been given the spec of loading three files into separate tables each month. Each month the folder they are in changes and the file name changes. There is also no guarantee that the file name will remain the same going forward.

I have solved the changing folders with various blogs and tips (thanks to the SSIS community!) but I am having trouble identifying which file goes to which table with the names changing.

The three files at the moment are called:

extract_mmes_ae_1415_APPROVED_80_12042016_6.txt
extract_mmes_ip_1415_APPROVED_81_12042016_6.txt
extract_mmes_apc_1415_APPROVED_82_12042016_6.txt

Next month I expect them to called something like:

extract_mmes_ae_1415_APPROVED_83_12042016_6.txt
extract_mmes_ip_1415_APPROVED_84_12042016_6.txt
extract_mmes_apc_1415_APPROVED_85_12042016_6.txt

They could also change names and the only thing that will remain consistent is the *ae*, *op* and *apc* sub-strings in the files as identifiers, but the string position could change. My gut is telling me, which could be wrong, is that I need to use a parameter that changes on each time to look for *ae*, *ip* and *apc* in the file name in the flat file source file name and then changes the destination table to be the one for each of three however I have no idea how to get the parameter.

Is any one able to provide a suggestion, or tell me wrong and to look at it another way.

Comment: i doubt the names will change other than the Date 12042016 to 12052016, but is only a guess... If you were given the spec for those files. It doesn't mention any filename creation rule? Maybe is time you ask for it. Anything else is just speculation.

Comment: Yes the date and number before the date will change each time however this doesn't help me as the data in each file is different yet the date the file is created will always be the same for each. I need to ensure that the AE file gets loaded into AE, IP to IP and so on as the data in each file is different and can't go in the same table.

Comment: As mentioend below, use three for each loop containers (one for each file) and use the _correct_ wildcard. For example the wildcard for your first file would be something like`extract_mmes_ae_*.txt `.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I didn't release wildcards would make it so simple. All done thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you should do is to creata a `Foreach Loop Container` to iterate through all files in your folder and **either** write a script for determining if it's the file you're interested in or not **or** use a `Foreach File Enumerator` as mentioned in another question: [SSIS Flat File Wildcard Filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634322/ssis-flat-file-wildcard-filename)

Comment: Thanks i'll try this.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I got it working thanks. what I didn't know was that I could use wildcards when specifying the file name. Thanks for the help.